# Previous() not working correctly

Tags: crystal-reports

I've a report with this group structure:

```
Question Type
 -> Question Block
   -> Question
     -> Compare level
```

In the compare level there are two possible values: 1 and 2. My body section is hidden for `compare_level = 1`. The values should be displayed in body section for `compare_level = 2` with `Previous()` but I get zero. If I disable hiding on `compare_level = 1` I see the values correct. So why is `Previous()` not working?

It seems that this error occurs only if I access a field of my datasource with `Previous(field)`. If I access a formula with `Previous(formula)` which returns the field value it works.

Thanks!

Comment: grouping might be affecting Previous(field)

Comment: Thank you, but how affects grouping it? There is a logic or not?

Comment: I think it is taking as Previous(field) detail from your previous group

Comment: Okay, but why because there is a record before in the current group.